# Improper integral of sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real-valued functions in $[a,\infty)$ that converges uniformly to $f$. Suppose $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ for all $x\geq a$ and $n\geq 1$, where $g:[a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, and that $\int\limits_a^{\infty}g(x)dx$ converges.

I have shown that $\int\limits_a^{\infty}f_n(x)dx, \int\limits_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converge, but I was unable to show that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_a^{\infty}f_n(x)dx = \int\limits_a^{\infty}f(x)dx
$$
I must use the fact that the improper integral of $g$ exists, since the convergence of the above integrals does not imply that the above limit is equal.

Comment: $$\int_a^{+\infty} f_n(x) - f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f_n(x) - f(x)\,dx + \int_b^{+\infty} f_n(x) - f(x)\,dx$$ Estimate $\lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert$ in terms of $g(x)$ on $[b,+\infty)$, choose an appropriate $b$, and then choose $n$ large to make the other integral small.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, can you elaborate more please? I have tried these sorts of methods, but lead me to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just formalizing Daniel Fischer's answer from the comments, for anyone who wants all the details.

The limit we're trying to prove is equivalent to,
$\left| \int_a^{\infty} f-f_n \right| < \epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

We have
$\left| \int_a^{\infty} f-f_n \right| \le \left| \int_a^{b} f-f_n \right| + \left| \int_b^{\infty} f-f_n \right|$.

By the bounds on $f$ and $f_n$ with respect to $g$, we have $|f-f_n| \le |f|+|f_n| \le 2g(x)$, so,

$\left| \int_b^{\infty} f-f_n \right| \le \int_b^{\infty} |f-f_n| \le \int_b^{\infty} 2g$.

Now choose $b$ sufficiently large such that $\int_b^{\infty} 2g < \epsilon/2$ (as guaranteed by the integrability of $g$).

With $b$ now fixed, we have for all $n$ sufficiently large that, by uniform convergence of $f_n \to f$,
$\left| \int_a^b f-f_n \right| < \epsilon/2$. We can conclude,
$\left| \int_a^{\infty} f-f_n \right| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2$
as desired.